# How does IntelliJ run a gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I really don't get how intelliJ is able to run my project... I was willing to run it on a normal terminal, and I can't find a way to run it

What I tried:

- create a Jar file and run it (doesn't work because I have external dependency that are not inside the jar)
- create a fat-Jar (doesn't work because it has more than 65535 entries)
- using `apply plugin: 'application'` (doesn't work because  *Unsupported class file major version 62*)

I mean, what am I supposed to do just to run a simple project from CLI without IntelliJ

`build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow'

// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
  jcenter()
}

compileJava   {
  sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
  targetCompatibility = '1.8'
}

configurations {
    sparkCompile // Configuration for Spark: should be included in the local
                 // class path both at compilation and at runtime, but should
                 // be excluded from the fat jar
    shadowCompile // Configuration for things that should be included in the shadow jar.
}

dependencies {
    sparkCompile 'org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.2.0'
    sparkCompile 'org.apache.spark:spark-mllib_2.11:2.2.0'
    sparkCompile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:2.7.2'
    shadowCompile 'com.beust:jcommander:1.72'
}

configurations.implementation.extendsFrom configurations.sparkCompile
configurations.implementation.extendsFrom configurations.shadowCompile

shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    configurations = [project.configurations.shadowCompile] // Exclude runtime-only path
}


apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.bdc.MyClass'
```

Comment: Can you show your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Sweeper sure, posted